# Difference in behaviour at runtime between local variable and a class field

Tags: c#, .net, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm trying to write a recursive method for finding the number of all the possible ways to travel from the top left to the bottom right corner of a *m* by *n* grid (without moving upwards).

The variable *key* is supposed to hold current values of *m* and *n*, but if I try to use the class field, this variable is behaving like it's one step behind or something.

The following code will end with unhandled exception:

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 1,1

It looks a lot like, say, when your initial *m* and *n* are 3 and 2 respectively, function of (1, 2) will try to add its *value* to the Dictionary with the key of "1,1":

```
class Finder
{
    public Finder()
    {
        memo = new(new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>
        { new KeyValuePair<string, ulong>("1,1", 1) });
    }

    private Dictionary<string, ulong> memo;
    private string key;
    private ulong value;

    public ulong FindPaths(int m, int n)
    {
        key = String.Format("{0},{1}", (m < n ? m : n), (m > n ? m : n));

        if (memo.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return memo[key];
        }

        if (m == 0 || n == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        value = FindPaths(m - 1, n) + FindPaths(m, n - 1);
        memo.Add(key, value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

And when I change the pre-calculated *key* in the `Add` method to the same expression that calculates it in the first place, the issue is gone:

```
memo.Add(String.Format("{0},{1}", (m < n ? m : n), (m > n ? m : n)), value);
```

And now, if we replace the class field with a local variable, everything is working like it is supposed to:

```
class Finder
{
    public Finder()
    {
        memo = new(new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>
        { new KeyValuePair<string, ulong>("1,1", 1) });
    }

    private Dictionary<string, ulong> memo;
    private ulong value;

    public ulong FindPaths(int m, int n)
    {
        string key;
        key = String.Format("{0},{1}", (m < n ? m : n), (m > n ? m : n));
        
        if (memo.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return memo[key];
        }

        if (m == 0 || n == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        value = FindPaths(m - 1, n) + FindPaths(m, n - 1);
        memo.Add(key, value);

        return value;
    }
}
```

Is this difference in behaviour caused by the fact that class fields are located on the heap while local variables are located on the stack? I would think that using a class field in a recursive method is quite more practical than creating a local every time the method calls itself.

Please, help me come to a deeper understanding of this subject.

Comment: Recursing with a field changes the value of *key*, corrupting the memo.Add(key, value) call.  Be sure to test early with *small* cases so you can see this go wrong when single-stepping with the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a member variable in your class, the reference exists exactly one time. when using a recursive function, all recursive calls work on the same memory base, so on the same contents which is in your class object.

if the variable is local in your function, in each function call it is a new storage and new variable content.

when using your upper code, a recursive call itself also changes the key value, then at the "add" command the key contents is different from before the recursive call.